# show Div relative to link click jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide, document-ready

I know there are other questions about this out on the forums but I can't seem to get this to work for me so I thought i'd just start my own.  I want to show a div below wherever the user might click the link on my page.  The HTML is like this;

```
<div class="DetailHeaderBar Expanded">
<span class="imgContainer"></span>
<span>John Smith</span>
<img class="TradeDetailsLink" alt="v" src="/Applications/Images/Icons/action_arrow.gif">
<a class="TradeDetailsLink" id="DetailsLink" href="#">Trade Details</a>
</div>

<div id="tradeDetailsSelector" class="ContextMenuPanel" style="position: absolute; display:none;">
    <div id="AvailableMoneyItem" class="ContextMenuItem"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:popupAvailableMoney(); return false;">View Available NFS Money</a></div>
    <div id="OpenOrdersItem" class="ContextMenuItem"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:redirectToTradeCentral(); return false;">View Open Orders</a></div>
    <div id="LockCashBufferItem" class="ContextMenuItem"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:redirectToModelManagement(); return false;">Add/Edit Locks or Cash Buffer</a></div>
</div>
```

with the Jquery being in the document.ready() function.  I just want to display the TradeDetailsSelector div directly under the "Trade Details" link when it's clicked. This code was modified from a different post that was said to work perfectly, but isn't for me.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$('div#DetailsLink').bind('click',function(event){
$('#tradeDetailsSelector').css('left',event.pageX);
$('#tradeDetailsSelector').css('top',event.pageY);
$('#tradeDetailsSelector').css('display','inline');
$("#tradeDetailsSelector").css("position","absolute");

});
})
```

Any help anyone could give me would be great, right now nothing is happening at all and the developer tools in IE aren't showing any errors in the console so i don't know.
Thank you,
NickG

Comment: `#DetailsLink` is a `<div>`, not an `<a>`. Also, `on()` is preferred over `bind()` as of 1.7: `$('#DetailsLink').on('click', function() { ... });`

Comment: Thank you for that, i feel stupid lol but I definitely needed your help it's been a long day already on this but this is definitely what i was looking for, i can do some other tweaks. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: @NickG, no need to feel stupid. Some times its nice to have more people looking at things we don't see anymore after working on the same thing.

Comment: @NickG Oops, switch `<div>` and `<a>` in my comment. Looks like you got what I meant though. And no worries, happens to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EcR9R/2/)**

I changed from .bind to [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you could also use [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/). I would suggest having the inline CSS on the CSS file, like in the demo I posted. I also removed `div` because the link is not a div. Anyway, if you have a ID which is unique you don't need the `div` or in this case `a` before.

This is what i changed to make it work:

```
 $('#DetailsLink').on('click', function (event) {
```

The whole code:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('#DetailsLink').on('click', function (event) {
        $('#tradeDetailsSelector').css('left', event.pageX);
        $('#tradeDetailsSelector').css('top', event.pageY + 10);
        $('#tradeDetailsSelector').css('display', 'inline');
        $("#tradeDetailsSelector").css("position", "absolute");

    });
})
```